# spring connect to database based on availability of connections

Tags: spring, jdbc

In a application we are having three databaseserver
1. db1 
2. db2 
3.db3
we have configured jndi for the above connections
if no connection in db1 ,then from db2 the application will establish connection,if no connection in db2 the application will establish connection in db2.how to acheive this spring jdbc template. The details of server
tomcat 8.0 server,spring 4.0 ,oracle

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to your question you can refer this source.

application.properties

```
spring.ds_items.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver 
spring.ds_items.url=jdbc:postgresql://srv0/test 
spring.ds_items.username=test0 
spring.ds_items.password=test0 


spring.ds_users.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver 
spring.ds_users.url=jdbc:postgresql://srv1/test 
spring.ds_users.username=test1 
spring.ds_users.password=test1
```

DatabaseItemsConfig.java

```
import javax.sql.DataSource; 

@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(name = "spring.ds_items") 
public class DatabaseItemsConfig extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration { 

    @Bean(name = "dsItems") 
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        return super.dataSource(); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "jdbcItems") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsItems) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsItems); 
    } 
}
```

DatabaseUsersConfig.java

```
import javax.sql.DataSource; 

@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(name = "spring.ds_users") 
public class DatabaseUsersConfig extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration { 

    @Bean(name = "dsUsers") 
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        return super.dataSource(); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "jdbcUsers") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsUsers) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsUsers); 
    } 

}
```

ItemRepository.java

```
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 

@Repository 
public class ItemRepository { 
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()); 

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("jdbcItems") 
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbc; 

    public Item getItem(long id) { 
        return jdbc.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM sb_item WHERE id=?", itemMapper, id); 
    } 

    private static final RowMapper<Item> itemMapper = new RowMapper<Item>() {
        public Item mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException { 
            Item item = new Item(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("title")); 
            item.price = rs.getDouble("id"); 
            return item; 
        } 
    }; 
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
   import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 

@Repository 
public class UserRepository { 
    protected final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()); 

    @Autowired 
    @Qualifier("jdbcUsers") 
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbc; 

    public User getUser(long id) { 
        return jdbc.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM sb_user WHERE id=?", userMapper, id); 
    } 

    private static final RowMapper<User> userMapper = new RowMapper<User>() {
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException { 
            User user = new User(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("name")); 
            user.alias = rs.getString("alias"); 
            return user; 
        } 
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks . how to use this in dao layer

Comment: I am using it like this you can refer to the edited post.

Comment: Thanks . how to use this in dao layer, i.e based on the availability of connection. i need to call the appropriate jdbctemplate